# What does function() in jQuery mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does function() in jquery mean? Because almost all of jquery function has a function() in it.

For example:

```
$(function(){
     //Do Stuff here
});
```

or:

```
$.each(element, function(something, something){
     //Do Stuff here
});
```

Im quite new to jquery, any help is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: This may help you: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

Comment: As jQuery is just JavaScript, and as functions are fundamental in JavaScript, it would be advisable for you to learn the basics of JavaScript before progressing too much further with jQuery.

Comment: `function() { ... }` is the syntax to define a function. In the above cases you are using a *function expression*. More resources to learn about functions: http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used when jQuery expects a callback `function`. In this case, its an anonymous `function`.

The `function` may or may not be passed arguments.

Named functions:

```
function name(){

}
```

Function Expression:

```
var name = function(){}
```

IIFE:

```
(function(){})();
```

`function` reference can be passed as an argument to another `function` which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

`function()` simply denotes a function call definition. It's important to note that a function can be passed as a parameter into an argument, and can be passed with no arguments itself.

Comment: When paired with the `function` keyword, the `()` don't denote the *call* of a function, but the parameters in the definition/creation of one. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

Comment: That is correct, and an important distinction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Above code this is a Anonymous Functions.

An anonymous function can be defined in similar way as a normal function but it would not have any name.

A anonymous function can be assigned to a variable or passed to a method