# What does this mean "jQuery(function ($) {})"?

Tags: jquery, sigils

What does the below line mean? It passes function($) as a parameter into jQuery?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Please don't answer, there are many duplicate .. [and yes, it passes a new "anonymous" function]

Comment: @user2864740 damn, was too slow to find a dup...

Comment: I can't find this exact scenario

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Beat me though! I know there are exact duplicates ("what does this idiomatic use of $.ready mean", eg.) but kept finding higher-level questions.

Comment: May still be worth the permutated phrasing.

Comment: @MikeLyons Found some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454631/jquery-newbie-what-does-jqueryfunction-means?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829847/jquery-function-what-does-it-mean?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226886/what-does-function-in-jquery-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It means, "treat this `$` as if I were calling `jQuery()` when I use `$()` anywhere inside this anonymous function."

Jquery documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/